# [Java][Glpk]Solve dual solution

Tags: java, linear-programming, glpk

I have a linear problem and I want to get optimal dual solution with GLPK on Java. I tried this :

```
parm = new glp_smcp();
parm.setMeth(GLPKConstants.GLP_DUAL);
GLPK.glp_init_smcp(parm);
ret = GLPK.glp_simplex(lp, parm);
```

but it seems there I always have primal Solution.
Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
 parm.setMeth(GLPKConstants.GLP_DUAL);
```

will select the dual simplex method. It does not give you the dual solution per se. (To be precise: afterwards you can retrieve both the primal and dual solution).

The way to retrieve the solution after solving is:

```
GLPK.glp_get_col_prim(lp,j)   // retrieve primal solution
GLPK.glp_get_row_dual(lp,i)   // retrieve duals
```

Remember in linear programming

- Dual Simplex Method
- The Dual of an LP problem
- Duals in a solution

are all different things. For more information please consult a book on Linear Programming (e.g. [Vanderbei](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461476291)).